# Error CS1014: A get or set accessor expected

Tags: c#

```
using System;

//Find the square root of a number for 10 values from user

class forLoop
{
    static void Main
    {

        double x;

        for(int i=10; i>0 && x>=0; i--)
        {


        Console.WriteLine("You have {0} remaining calculations left", i);
        Console.Write("Please enter a positive number: ");

        x = double.Parse((Console.ReadLine());
        x = Math.Sqrt(x);

        Console.WriteLine("The square root is {0}", x);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        }

    Console.WriteLine("You have 0 remaining calculations left");

    }

}
```

I need help on this C# problem: Why does the error: "A get or set accessor expected" come up at compile time?

Comment: where is the method  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed the `()` in method declaration. Thus, the compiler thinks at some level that you're declaring a Property (albeit it would then throw an error about the `void` type), not a Method

```
// Property
public int Property
{
    get { return _field; }
    set { _field = value; }
}

// Property, albeit a get-only property
public int Property => _field;

// Method
public int Method()
{
    return _field;
}

// Method
public int Method() => _field;
```

**UPDATE**: Since this is still being seen, I've updated the example values to better reflect their underlying types, and included examples of expression bodies introduced with C# 6

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses (`()`) in the method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses is required to differentiate a method from a property that requires the [get/set syntax](http://www.dotnetperls.com/property)